# Ruby Rails: Controller not passing ID correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, controller

I have a link that toggles a true/false on an attribute in the database. I have two versions of this link for two different attributes, one works and the other doesn't, except when I force a specific ID it works fine.

View of working link:

```
<h1><%= link_to "Toggle True", toggle_completed_true_task_path(@task), :remote => true %></h1>

<h1><%= link_to "Toggle False", toggle_completed_false_task_path(@task), :remote => true %></h1>
```

View of working controller:

```
respond_to :html, :js
  def toggle_completed_true
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attributes(:completed => true)
  end

  respond_to :html, :js
  def toggle_completed_false
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attributes(:completed => false)
  end
```

View of failing link:

```
<h1><%= link_to "Toggle True", toggle_confirmed_true_task_path(@task), :remote => true %></h1>

<h1><%= link_to "Toggle False", toggle_confirmed_false_task_path(@task), :remote => true %></h1>
```

View of failing controller:

```
respond_to :html, :js
  def toggle_confirmed_true
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attributes(:confirmed => true)
  end

  respond_to :html, :js
  def toggle_confirmed_false
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attributes(:confirmed => false)
  end
```

I've been working on this for hours and for the life of me I cannot see why one should be failing and the other working. *note* Both of these appear on the same page and the one that doesn't work will work if I pass in a specific ID like so:

```
<h1><%= link_to "Toggle True", toggle_confirmed_true_task_path(12), :remote => true %></h1>
```

The specific error I get with the variable pass is:
"No route matches {:action=>"toggle_confirmed_true", :controller=>"tasks", :id=>nil"

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you remember to add it to your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1):

Run "rake routes" command. This will print all of your routes, in the same order they appear in routes.rb.  Confirm the order.

The path you are looking for should come first in the order.

Comment: I've done that, here are the routes working and not working included `toggle_confirmed_true_task GET    /tasks/:id/toggle_confirmed_true(.:format)               tasks#toggle_confirmed_true
   toggle_confirmed_false_task GET    /tasks/:id/toggle_confirmed_false(.:format)              tasks#toggle_confirmed_false
    toggle_completed_true_task GET    /tasks/:id/toggle_completed_true(.:format)               tasks#toggle_completed_true
   toggle_completed_false_task GET    /tasks/:id/toggle_completed_false(.:format)              tasks#toggle_completed_false`

Comment: Error says "id" is coming as nil, verify the @task object, it shouldn't be null or empty.  The specific error I get with the variable pass is: "No route matches {:action=>"toggle_confirmed_true", :controller=>"tasks", :id=>nil"